# Failed to install nvidia driver on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, software-sources

I've run an update and upgrade after I rebooted. 
When I did that I realised that the nvidia driver isn't there anymore.

I've tried everything I know from :

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall nvidia-current-update
```

to

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then reinstalled it in vain as I keep getting the error

```
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

here's my sources.list:

```
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
```

Comment: Take a look at your Software Sources file: `/etc/apt/sources.list` and check to see if you added an additional Nvidia repository to it that it preventing you from installing the nvidia-current package from the Ubuntu Software Center, because that software source has a more recent version of the same package in it.

Comment: i think i did but i don't know which one(i can't make the difference) can you advise me which on? recently i've ad ppa :sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa should i upload my sources.list content?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what's causing your problem. Edit your question and add your sources.list file to it so it can be determined which lines in your sources.list file need to be deleted.

Comment: it's uploaded can you see the problems?

Comment: I checked in the Ubuntu 13.10 sources.list file at [Ubuntu Saucy Packages and Repositories](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Saucy_Packages_and_Repositories) website and there is only one line in your sources.list file that doesn't match. It's the line near the end that says: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ saucy partner`. I dont know what this line does, but you could try commenting it out by putting `## ` characters before it. You need to run `sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list` to edit sources.list, Ctrl+O and after that Enter to save and Ctrl+X to exit nano. Then run:`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: oki i've done what u said it doesn't seem to make any difference oki so last resort i just found on the web a way to reset the sources.list to default through http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ here's a link http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/restore-your-sources-list-to-defaults.html is it safe to do that?

Comment: The safest way to do it is to compare it with the list at "Ubuntu Saucy Packages and Repositories" which has some extra repositories in it, but at least you know that all the repositories in your sources.list are OK if they are also in the example sources.list file from the "Ubuntu Saucy Packages and Repositories" website.

Comment: oki can u paste a link so i can verify it and thx

Comment: Link to  "Ubuntu Saucy Packages and Repositories": http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Saucy_Packages_and_Repositories

Comment: oki i think i found what happened it's a bug in the new version https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-experimental-310/+bug/1085044 anyone thx a lot for ur assistance sir i appriciate it

Comment: I'm happy that you solved your problem, especially because it's a bug and bugs can sometimes take forever to find. Since I don't know exactly what you did, I'm not going to post an answer, but you can answer your own question (if that's what you want to do) after waiting 2 hours after you asked the original question.

Comment: sry for taking so long to answer actually if you want you can put an answer so i mark the post and solved again thx for your time sir